# Array value store in variable in Nodered

Tags: javascript, json, node-red

I am trying to save co2 value each 5 minutes interval. ut when i get new value, it automatically remove old value and overwrite at same position in array.
here is my code:

```
var count=context.get('count') || 0;
count +=1;
context.set('count',count);
if (count == 4 )  {
context.set("count", 0);
}
var i = 0;
var wert = global.wert-1;
for(i = 1; i <= count; i++){
wert[count-1] = msg.payload.decoded.co2;
}
msg.payload = wert;
return msg;
```

I am counting 1 to 4 and saving each co2 value each 5 minutes interval. After 4 count, count should be reset to 1. again count 1 to 4 and so on. but something is wrong. i tried different ways. but doesn't work.
can anyone tell me, where am i doing mistake?
Thank you in advance.
kind regards

Comment: What do you think `var wert = global.wert-1;` is doing when you access it as an array later on?

Comment: I have seen some online forum. so they explained that we should use declare variable as globe. Wert = Value(English)  We tried but not success. :(

Comment: No, `global` is just the old way to access the context